# In edge browser, javascript for read-out-loud not syncing words

Tags: javascript

This needs to be run in Edge browser to get it to read-out-loud.

The problem i'm having is that the highlighted word is not in sync with the read-out-loud.   any ideas?

```js
    const contentDiv = document.getElementById('content');
    const originalText = contentDiv.textContent || contentDiv.innerText;
    
    contentDiv.innerHTML = '';
    
    Array.from(originalText).forEach(character => {
        if (character === '\n') {
            contentDiv.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
        } else {
            const span = document.createElement('span');
            span.textContent = character;
            contentDiv.appendChild(span);
        }
    });

    let desiredVoice = null;
    window.speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = function() {
        desiredVoice = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices().find(voice => voice.name === "Microsoft Zira - English (United States)");
    }


function readOutLoud() {
    const synth = window.speechSynthesis;
    const utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(originalText);

    if (desiredVoice) {
        utterance.voice = desiredVoice;
    }

    utterance.rate = 2.5;

    const spans = Array.from(contentDiv.children);

    // Function to remove highlight from all characters
    function removeHighlight() {
        spans.forEach(span => span.classList.remove('highlight'));
    }
    
    let lastCharIndex = 0;
    
    utterance.onboundary = (event) => {
        if (event.name === 'word') {
            const wordStart = lastCharIndex;
            const wordEnd = event.charIndex;
            
            setTimeout(() => {
                removeHighlight();  // Remove highlight before applying it to the current word
                for (let i = wordStart; i < wordEnd; i++) {
                    spans[i] && spans[i].classList.add('highlight');
                }
            }, 50);
            
            lastCharIndex = wordEnd;
        }
    };

    synth.speak(utterance);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Read Out Loud with Highlighting</title>
    <style>
        .highlight {
            background-color: yellow;
        }
        pre {
            white-space: pre-wrap;
            white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
            white-space: -pre-wrap;
            white-space: -o-pre-wrap;
            word-wrap: break-word;
        }       
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="readOutLoud()">Read Out Loud</button>
    <pre>
        <div id="content">
CHAR1: Did you say two pizzas? My cybernetic body requires at least 20... 

CHAR2: Ooh, are there gluten-free options? I'm on a new macrobiotic kick.

CHAR3: Friends, please! The two pizzas are symbolic. It's about assembling a small, cross-functional team. 

CHAR4: Well I'm game for fresh thinking and free grub!

        </div>`
    </pre>

<script>
    const contentDiv = document.getElementById('content');
    const originalText = contentDiv.textContent || contentDiv.innerText;
    
    contentDiv.innerHTML = '';
    
    Array.from(originalText).forEach(character => {
        if (character === '\n') {
            contentDiv.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
        } else {
            const span = document.createElement('span');
            span.textContent = character;
            contentDiv.appendChild(span);
        }
    });

    let desiredVoice = null;
    window.speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = function() {
        desiredVoice = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices().find(voice => voice.name === "Microsoft Zira - English (United States)");
    }


function readOutLoud() {
    const synth = window.speechSynthesis;
    const utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(originalText);

    if (desiredVoice) {
        utterance.voice = desiredVoice;
    }

    utterance.rate = 2.5;

    const spans = Array.from(contentDiv.children);

    // Function to remove highlight from all characters
    function removeHighlight() {
        spans.forEach(span => span.classList.remove('highlight'));
    }
    
    let lastCharIndex = 0;
    
    utterance.onboundary = (event) => {
        if (event.name === 'word') {
            const wordStart = lastCharIndex;
            const wordEnd = event.charIndex;
            
            setTimeout(() => {
                removeHighlight();  // Remove highlight before applying it to the current word
                for (let i = wordStart; i < wordEnd; i++) {
                    spans[i] && spans[i].classList.add('highlight');
                }
            }, 50);
            
            lastCharIndex = wordEnd;
        }
    };

    synth.speak(utterance);
}

</script>


</body>
</html>
```